# How to insert numbers into an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, printing

I have been asked by my programming professor a program which:

- Adds numbers into an array
- Prints the result

But there must be a boolean function which returns `true` if the insertion is correct, then `false` when the array is full.

The program I wrote runs, and works fine until I have to print the resulting array: it prints random numbers, which are very far away from the numbers I had entered.
I assume there are problems with saving in memory the numbers I wrote.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool insert(int v[], int &elements, int entered_number);
int maxDim=10;

int main(){
    
    int maxDim=10;
    int array[maxDim];
    int elements=0;
    int number;
    
    while(insert(array, elements, number)){
        
        cout << "Number entered successfully." << endl;
        
    }
    
    cout << "Array is composed of: ";
    for (int i=0; i<elements; i++)
        cout << array[i] << ", ";
    cout << endl;
    
    
}

bool insert(int v[], int &elements, int entered_number){
    
    if (elements<maxDim){
        
        cout << "Enter a number: " << endl;
        cin >> entered_number;
        
        for (int i=0; i<maxDim; i++){
            
            v[i]=entered_number;
            elements++;
            return true;
            
        }
    
    }else{
        
        cout << "Array is full." << endl;
        return false;
        
    }
        
}
```

Any hints? What am I doing wrong?

The program must:

- Accept entering numbers until array is full, returning `true` whenever a number can be entered
- Print the resulting array

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity to learn to use a *debugger*.  A debugger allows you to single-step through your code and watch contents of variables.  Experience using a debugger will be invaluable as your career and skills progress.

Comment: You don't need or want a for loop in your insert function. You just want to get 1 number and place in the next position.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: The problem is missing `constexpr` on `constexpr int maxDim = 10;`.  It's not a user input or other value changing at runtime.  The line you took issue with is fine.

Comment: Which one, @BenVoigt, the first or the second copy of this line?

Comment: While it's clear this code won't produce the desired output, I can't see a reason why it would output random numbers.

Comment: Pop quiz: @MarkRansom, can you figure out how it is logically possible for `insert()` to set anything other than `v[0]` to any value, leaving the rest of the array uninitialized random garbage?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I see a `for` loop that should be setting every element of the array, as long as it runs once.

Comment: Try:  `v[elements++]=entered_number;` instead of the loop.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sorry, I just looked again and discovered why the loop is ineffective.

Comment: The first comment is blown way out of proportion. It's fixed with literally one word. Declaring the variable `maxDim` as `constexpr` solves the issue and doesn't require a full paragraph bemoaning the state of the world and otherwise being a <not nice person>. But "oh no there are typos in a newbie's program. Better go nuclear" is what's liked on this site.

Comment: I edited the code and now it works; deleted `maxDim` and added `#define MAXDIM 10` so anyone won't harrass me for being a 4-days entry newbie coder. Then, I removed the `for` cycle which I understood was saving the number always in the first position. It works properly now.

Comment: @Yuzeq A take on your program would be to not make macros or global variables at all. That's usually appreciated. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/7cMsr5c79)